# CSS counter output mismatch

Tags: css

Could someone please explain why in the `section` counter value is printed 0 in all `h2` tags?

Here is the source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    counter-reset: section;
    counter-reset: subsection;
}

h1::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Section " counter(section) ". ";
}

h2::before {
    counter-increment: subsection;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>HTML tutorials:</h1>
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>

<h1>Scripting tutorials:</h1>
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<h2>VBScript</h2>

<h1>XML tutorials:</h1>
<h2>XML</h2>
<h2>XSL</h2>

<p><b>Note:</b> IE8 supports these properties only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just remove `counter-reset: subsection;`

Comment: I agree but want to understand why "section" counter is showing value 0 in the output? Thanks for help!

Comment: Because you set to 0 before the increment starts

Comment: then why subsection is not set 0 and increasing each time with h2 tags and section shows value 1 for h1 tags and 0 for h2 tags?

Answer (score 2):

In your solution there are two `counter-reset` properties in the `body` tag:

```
body {
    counter-reset: section;     
    counter-reset: subsection;
}
```

As the name suggests, CSS are **cascading**, therefore the second occurrence of the `counter-reset` property overrides the first one. As a result `counter-reset: section;` will be overwritten by `counter-reset: subsection;` and `section` reset won't be defined at all.

**Solutions**

1. Move the `subsection` counter into `h1` tag. Then the `subsection` counter will reset for each `h1` tag:

   ```
   body {
       counter-reset: section; 
   }

   h1 {
       counter-reset: section; 
   }
   ```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}

h1 { 
    counter-reset: subsection; 
}

h1::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Section " counter(section) ". ";
}

h2::before {
    counter-increment: subsection;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>HTML tutorials:</h1>
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>

<h1>Scripting tutorials:</h1>
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<h2>VBScript</h2>

<h1>XML tutorials:</h1>
<h2>XML</h2>
<h2>XSL</h2>

<p><b>Note:</b> IE8 supports these properties only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

2. Define  the `subsection` counter inline with the `section` counter, as [@Temani suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52409155/2869093). Then the `subsection` counter won't reset:

   ```
   body {
       counter-reset: section subsection; 
   }
   ```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    counter-reset: section subsection;
}

h1::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Section " counter(section) ". ";
}

h2::before {
    counter-increment: subsection;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>HTML tutorials:</h1>
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>

<h1>Scripting tutorials:</h1>
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<h2>VBScript</h2>

<h1>XML tutorials:</h1>
<h2>XML</h2>
<h2>XSL</h2>

<p><b>Note:</b> IE8 supports these properties only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree but want to understand why "section" counter is showing value 0 in the output for all h2 tags but 1 for h1 tags? Thanks for help!

Comment: no need to copy past from the other answer ;) what is the purpose of editing your answer to say exactly what I already said in mine?

Comment: Compare our code snippets. They are not the same. Beyond that I refer to your answer in one of the solutions... The purpose of my edit was to give the most comprehensive answer in one place.

Comment: another query is how does **counters** is working in the following program saved at https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVG5V4QLO14W

I am new so would appreciate your response.

Comment: It is quite the same issue with cascading. If a new `<ol>` tag is open, it's parent gets overridden. That is why you get 2.1, 2.2, etc.

Comment: `Compare our code snippets. They are not the same` : there is only one tag different and as a developer you know that they are exactly the same ;) .. `The purpose of my edit was to give the most comprehensive answer in one place` : so you take another answer, you use its content and you make it yours, nice interpretation of *comprehensive answer*

Comment: This one difference results in a different execution of the code... Compare numbering in my 1st and 2nd solution (**indicated as yours**). OP asked me a question in comments, so I had to update my question.

Comment: @raven03 Since you are new, I'd suggest to don't use w3schools as a learning reference, since they explain everything **very** poorly. I recommend to use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) to look up specific behaviours of tags, rule-sets etc. They have good written "Introductions" into HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I promise you, if you get familiar with the MDN you won't go back to w3schools

Answer (score 2):

The hidden trick here is that you are overriding a property. You are using `counter-reset` twice in the same block so only the last one will be considered, that's why the `subsection` is ok and not the `section`.

[image]

If you move one of the `counter-reset` to the `html` for example it will behave like intended:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

html {
  counter-reset: subsection;
}

h1::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(section) ". ";
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

```html
<h1>HTML tutorials:</h1>
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>

<h1>Scripting tutorials:</h1>
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<h2>VBScript</h2>

<h1>XML tutorials:</h1>
<h2>XML</h2>
<h2>XSL</h2>

<p><b>Note:</b> IE8 supports these properties only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>
```

Or use you can reset both counter with the same property:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section subsection;
}


h1::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(section) ". ";
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

```html
<h1>HTML tutorials:</h1>
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>

<h1>Scripting tutorials:</h1>
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<h2>VBScript</h2>

<h1>XML tutorials:</h1>
<h2>XML</h2>
<h2>XSL</h2>

<p><b>Note:</b> IE8 supports these properties only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>
```